# Listbox shows elements wrongly after scrolling

Tags: c#, listbox, observablecollection, windows-phone-8.1, inotifypropertychanged

In my windows phone 8.1 application I have a listbox when initially loading everything I want to show in the listbox everything is fine. However after scrolling some of the elements will be shown incorrectly. This seems completely random.

The forementioned listbox looks like this in xaml:

```
            <ListBox Name="MainPage_List" Grid.Column="0" Background="#EDEDED" >
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Components:MyUserControl />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

As you can see its datatemplate is linked to a usercontrol. In this UserControl I have a DataContextChanged event. Which looks like this:

```
private void DataContextChanged(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (mySource == null)
        {
            mySource = DataContext as Message;
        }

        if (mySource != null)
        {
            if (mySource.Source_Type == SourceTypes.Type1)
            {
                MyGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                MyOtherGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else if (mySource.Source_Type == SourceTypes.Type2)
            {
                MyOtherGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                MyGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

I check multiple types and variables here and depending on that I set other things visible or load other images. This works fine. However when scrolling through the list sometimes some of the elements will be shown differently than they should. Even when I make sure the code that decides which elements will be shown is not used again.

The source of the list is a custom class enheriting from ObservableCollection using a custom class that enherits from INotifyPropertyChanged.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Or why this happens and how to get around this?

Comment: You could try setting the Height of MyUserControl or ListBoxItem, if all items have the same height. Also, if you don't have too many items, you could try setting the ListBox's ItemsPanel to be a StackPanel.

Comment: The problem is not height related. Maybe I didn't specify enough. The problem is that I want to show different kind of messages and sometimes it shows a profile picture and other times not. The sizes stay the same, and this is correct. However sometimes it is shown with a profile picture while it should not be shown with a profile picture or vice versa.

Comment: Okay, the Height was just a guess :P but changing to StackPanel might work. Also, are you sure that the DataContextChanged is working correctly?

Comment: DataContextChanged is working. I stepped through it multiple times. It does everything exactly as expected. I might look into the stackpanel thing. But I need to show a variable amount of elements in that list. Which varies from 0 to as many as fit in memory.

Comment: Well, it will take you about a minute and you'll know if it fixes the issue. ;) Also, could you please share the code that raises the DataContextChanged event?

Comment: The stackpanel thing did not help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57386/discussion-between-yasen-and-werewolfboy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion with WereWolfBoy we found the problem.

It is related to the default ItemsPanel of the ListBox which is a [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.ui.xaml.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.Aspx). It reuses the controls from the ItemTemplate of the ListBox and changes their DataContext when necessary to display different items. Unlike normal StackPanel, it does NOT create separate controls for different items.

For this to work, the items must refresh when the DataContext changes. And here's the actual problem. Because of this code:

```
    if (mySource == null)
    {
        mySource = DataContext as Message;
    }
```

the DataContext was actually loaded just once, and subsequent changes did not affect the UI. Removing the `if` and getting the DataContext every time it changes fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a result of virtualization.
If your list is long enough, there is a reuse of controls for items in it.
Imagine you have a list with 1000 items in it, but the listbox only has 30 control instances that are re-used when you scroll up and down.
If this is the case, you will see the wrong behavior repeatin ever X items.

In order to solve this problem, I would recommend that instead of using DataContextChanged, you should expose a property as DependencyProperty.

In your data template, bind to this property and this will do the trick for you.

```
public bool ShowMyGrid
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowMyGridProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ShowMyGridProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowMyGridProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ShowMyGrid", typeof(bool), typeof(MyUserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, ShowMyGridCallback));


static void ShowMyGridCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var myControl = d as MyUserControl1;
    bool newVal = (bool)e.NewValue;
    if (newVal)
    {
        myControl.MyGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        myControl.MyOtherGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        myControl.MyGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        myControl.MyOtherGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. First off UIPropertyMetaData does not exist, so instead I used: new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MyCallback)). I also changed the public bool ShowMyGrid into public customObject ShowMyGrid. Because there is more than one variable (within the object) I want to check. also, I needed to change GetValue and SetValue in the ShowMyGrid to this.GetValue and this.SetValue. I've put a breakpoint in the MyCallback and it never reaches it.

Comment: Can you please paste your relevant code here? It is a bit hard to understand what exactly you did. My guess is overriding the setter and getter made you skip the callback. Try using propdp code snippet...

Comment: I did paste all the relevant code. But the problem is already solved. Thanks anyway.